# Jquery not executing in .load Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue with the .load function. The loaded page is not executing the Jquery in the loaded div. I have ensured that the Jquery is indeed in the tag. I am thinking there is an issue with the .load call but I am new to this. Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var partyid = '<?php echo sanitize_text_field($_GET["Party_ID"]); ?>';
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    if (localStorage.user2==localStorage.username2){
        var e = document.getElementById('display');
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';

        $('#Submission-2').load('http://example.com/play/?Party_ID=' + partyid + ' #Submission' );
        refresh();
    }
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh() 
{ 
    setTimeout( function() { 
        $('#Submission-2').fadeOut('slow').load('http://example.com/play/?Party_ID=' + partyid + ' #Submission'  , function() {
            var username = '<?php echo $party_information[0]->Username; ?>';
            if (document.getElementById('total').value!=username){
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
        $('#Submission-2').fadeIn('slow').load('http://example.com/play/?Party_ID=' + partyid + ' #Submission' );
        {
            refresh();
        }
    }, 5000); 
}
</script>
```

Jquery which is not executing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#Answertoggle3 .lietruth").click(function(){
    jQuery("#Answertoggle3 .lietruth").removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active'); 
});
jQuery("#Answertoggle2 .lietruth").click(function(){
    jQuery("#Answertoggle2 .lietruth").removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active'); 
});
jQuery("#Answertoggle1 .lietruth").click(function(){
    jQuery("#Answertoggle1 .lietruth").removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active'); 
});
</script>
```

Also instead of the executing window.location.reload(); function. I would like to end the execution of the containing function refresh(). Which refreshes after every 5 seconds. So basically stop the refreshing.

Comment: One thing that you would need to know is that PHP and Javascript run independently.. So if you are assuming that your PHP line will be executed before Javascript or the other way round - it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Answertoggle3 .lietruth").click(function(){
                $("#Answertoggle3 .lietruth").removeClass('active');
                $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
        });
        $("#Answertoggle2 .lietruth").click(function(){
                $("#Answertoggle2 .lietruth").removeClass('active');
                $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
        });
        $("#Answertoggle1 .lietruth").click(function(){
                $("#Answertoggle1 .lietruth").removeClass('active');
                $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: still doesn't not execute

Comment: @Dario Are you using this in the head of the document?

Comment: i added it to the head still no success

Answer (score 0):

This is what I added and it made the toggle work temporarily through the fadeOut.load and fadeIn. I need to stop the refresh() function from executing when this is true.

```
if (document.getElementById('total').value!=username)
```

instead of the

```
window.location.reload();
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh() 
{ 
var quitfunction = 0;
 setTimeout( function() { 
$('#Submission-2').fadeOut('slow').load('http://example.com/play-with-friends/?Party_ID=' + partyid + ' #Submission' ,function() {
jQuery("#Answertoggle3 .lietruth").click(function(){
        jQuery("#Answertoggle3 .lietruth").removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active'); 
});
jQuery("#Answertoggle2 .lietruth").click(function(){
        jQuery("#Answertoggle2 .lietruth").removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active'); 
});
jQuery("#Answertoggle1 .lietruth").click(function(){
        jQuery("#Answertoggle1 .lietruth").removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active'); 
});
var username = '<?php echo $party_information[0]->Username; ?>';
if (document.getElementById('total').value!=username)
{
window.location.reload();
}
        });
$('#Submission-2').fadeIn('slow').load('http://example.com/play-with-friends/?Party_ID=' + partyid + ' #Submission' );
{
if (quitfunction==1)
return;
refresh();
}
 }, 5000); 
}
</script>
```